SSL Error when running Openshift AI Pipeline from code
I made an Elyra Pipeline en Openshift AI and I have submited to pipeline server ok.
I tried to run the pipeline fromPython code:
import os
import kfp_tekton
import os

token = "[my_token]"
route = "[My_projectURL]"
client = kfp_tekton.TektonClient(host=route, existing_token=token)


but I got this error:
MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='console-openshift-console.apps.lab-ai.cloud.semperti.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /k8s/cluster/projects/rhoai-demo/apis/v1beta1/healthz (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)')))
I cant run pipeline from python code in Openshift AI, !!!

You have 2 options that could work (didnt try them, but should work according to docs):

provide your self signed cert while creating client via cert_path:

client = kfp_tekton.TektonClient(
    host=route,
    existing_token=token,
    ssl_ca_cert=cert_path
 )


Disable SSL validation via verify_ssl=false

client = kfp_tekton.TektonClient(
    host=route,
    existing_token=token,
    verify_ssl=false
 )

